# Typescript generic restricted by extend, returned from function

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, tsc

I'm not sure how to put this into words, so here is an example

```
type NonVoid = Object | object;

type Something<T> = {
    test: string
} & (T extends NonVoid ? {
    requiredWhenNonVoid: T
} : {
    requiredWhenNonVoid?: undefined
});


function testFunc1<A extends NonVoid>(a: A): Something<NonVoid> {
    return {
        test: 'test',
        requiredWhenNonVoid: a
    };
}

function testFunc2<A extends NonVoid>(a: A): Something<A> {
    return {
        test: 'test',
        requiredWhenNonVoid: a // <-- why error here? A cannot be void??
    };
}
```

On playground: [click here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20NonVoid%20%3D%20Object%20%7C%20object%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Something%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%20%26%20(T%20extends%20NonVoid%20%3F%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20requiredWhenNonVoid%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%20%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20requiredWhenNonVoid%3F%3A%20undefined%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20testFunc1%3CA%20extends%20NonVoid%3E(a%3A%20A)%3A%20Something%3CNonVoid%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20test%3A%20'test'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20requiredWhenNonVoid%3A%20a%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20testFunc2%3CA%20extends%20NonVoid%3E(a%3A%20A)%3A%20Something%3CA%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20test%3A%20'test'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20requiredWhenNonVoid%3A%20a%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20why%20error%20here%3F%20A%20cannot%20be%20void%3F%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D)

The question is, **why does `testFunc2` have the following error**?

> Type '{ test: string; requiredWhenNonVoid: A; }' is not assignable to type 'Something'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'requiredWhenNonVoid' does not exist in type 'Something'. Did you mean to write 'requiredWhenNonVoid'?

It seems that the compiler doesn't know that `Something` can only be

```
type Something<T> = {
    test: string
} & {
    requiredWhenNonVoid: T
};
```

in that case.

Is this something that should be classed as a bug and can be fixed in the compiler, or am I missing something?

Comment: Logged https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25564 because TypeScript shouldn't have suggested the same property name it was complaining about!

Comment: Great! Do you know why it's actually complaining?